# Using timers in vb

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I do not understand how to utilize the timers in vb.net I want to make a simple program where when I press a button the timer starts and the label changes it's number every second until 60 seconds have passed. I think I should put this in the button event

```
Timer1.Start()
```

But I am unsure of what to do from there. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: WinForms?  Then use the Tick event, put your code in there.  Set the timer's interval property in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `Timer1.Start()` starts the timer, but you need to declare how often the timer ticks.

```
Timer1.Interval = 1000
```

will make the timer tick every 1000 miliseconds, or 1 sec. The actions that you want to happen for the timer go in the `Timer_Tick` event handler.

In order to allow the label to increment you could use a global variable:

```
Public Class MainBox

Dim counter As Int

Private Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) HandlesTimer1.Tick<action>
    counter = counter + 1
    label1.Text = counter
End Sub
```

Comment: So in the tick event I should put Label1.Text = something, but what do I use for something in order to reference what second the timer is on?

Comment: Yes, in the `Timer1_Tick` event set the label to what you want.

Comment: Well to reference how far along the Timer is, you can update the label every 1000 millisecond to increment. Look above.

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain it a little better.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the Tick event handler that will do the actions when time ticks (it will tick every interval - in miliseconds -  defined in `INTERVAL` property):

**Start the timer:**

```
Timer1.Start()
```

**Define INTERVAL property (2 seconds in the following example)**:

```
Timer1.Interval = 2000
```

**Define the event handler**

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    <action>
    IF <condition> THEN Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

If you want you can stop the timer using `Timer1.Stop()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable the Timer and set interval (1000 should be good enough, but you can leave the default 100). Inside a Tick handler put code to refresh the label. As you start the timer, remember the start time (`Date.Now`). Then, at every tick:

```
lbl.Text = Date.Now.Subtract(startDate).TotalSeconds.ToString("N0")
```